# camel cxf jax-ws custom result-type

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, apache-camel

This is my route:

```
this.from("cxf://service?serviceClass=ExampleInterface")
    .process(new ProcessorXY())
    .log("Example finished");
```

And this my javaclass:

```
@WebService(name = "service", targetNamespace = "http://ws.test/")
public interface ExampleInterface {
    @WebMethod
    void noticeSomething();
}
```

Is there a way to take care of the resulttype to give some special information to the caller?
i.e. if execution was successfully.

Comment: Sammy a web service call that fails will normally return a 403, 404 or 500 error codes as part of the HTTP protocol. So I am not sure what you mean if execution was successful. Could you please clarify.

Comment: I think, so was the hint to what was wrong with my idea. I wanted something like wrapping the call and if this isn't done in the error-handler, than an http- or soap or whatever-error  is returned. Thx, I think it was too late...

Comment: If you want send the response back the client, you'd better return a response object instead of using one way operation.